# The latest centos:8 docker image cannot run yum

Tags: docker, yum, centos8

With the latest centos:8 docker.hub image I cannot run yum. All yum commands fail with the error message `Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist`.

This can be reproduced like so:

```
$ docker pull centos:8
8: Pulling from library/centos
Digest: sha256:a27fd8080b517143cbbbab9dfb7c8571c40d67d534bbdee55bd6c473f432b177
Status: Image is up to date for centos:8
docker.io/library/centos:8

$ docker run -it --init --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --network=host centos:8 /bin/bash

[root@docker-desktop /]# yum clean all
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C.UTF-8
0 files removed

[root@docker-desktop /]# yum update
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C.UTF-8
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                                                                                                                                                                                         988  B/s |  38  B     00:00    
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist
```

I'm not sure whether this is specific to the docker image or is a broader centos:8 issue. I see [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993633/yum-dnf-error-failed-to-download-metadata-for-repo) about this from over a year ago which suggest modifying `/etc/yum/vars/releasever` or removing `/var/cache/dnf`, but that `releasever` file doesn't exist in this image and removing that `dnf` cache does not help.

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: CentOS 8 packages were removed from official mirrors today. Answer to this question could be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926799/centos-through-vm-no-urls-in-mirrorlist

Comment: Thank you @Sergei. That's the answer I needed. Unfortunately the issue is so new it didn't show up in my searches. I'm not sure whether this should be marked as a duplicate or not. Seems like this question belongs better in serverfault rather than stackoverflow. I'll leave that to the wisdom of our moderators.